# oracle - Temp table vs. Permanent table

Tags: oracle, temp-tables

In Oracle, what is the difference between temp and permanent tables?

Answer (score 10):

The content of a temporary table in Oracle is only visible for the current session or the current transaction.

Therefore they are perfect for temporary data. No worry that other users see (and get confused by) the data. No need to explicitly clean up after you.

Also, you don't generate REDO for a temporary table as it will never be used 9eg for restore). As such they can be faster.

Comment: Also, you don't generate REDO for a temporary table as it will never be used 9eg for restore). As such they can be faster.

Answer (score 0):

For an overview of all Oracle table types, including temporary, see [the Oracle Concepts Guide](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/schema.htm#sthref686).